# How to configure Spring App-context.xml for Tibco using jndi and SSL?

Tags: spring, ssl, jms, tibco

Does anyone have a tutorial/example for an app-context.xml for Spring to connect through an ssl server using jndi to TIBCO jms queue? I have not been able to find one.

Comment: it's not for Spring, but the following article might help you get started http://www.bluechaos.be/blogs/index.php/2009/02/how-to-configure-hermesjms-access-for-ti